# TypeError: Cannot read property of 'db' undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am new coder and developing To-Do App. I want to connect my app to mongoDB Atlas database from VSC editor Terminal. I use Node.js (Express) and mongoDB Atlas. When I uninstall Node.js and start code from scratch, it works fine because code is all OK but next day when I get back to the same project and run it, it doesn`t work anymore. It shows up an error. You may check this terrible error here on this link: https://prnt.sc/u8paeg

```js
let express = require('express')
let mongodb = require('mongodb')

let app = express()
let db

let connectionString ='mongodb+srv://akhtarayaz:SpreadLoveEverywhere@cluster0.yfwfa.mongodb.net/Users?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
mongodb.connect(connectionString, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true}, function(err, client){ 
  db = client.db()
  app.listen(3000)
  if (err) {
    throw err;
}  
})

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}))

app.get('/', function(req, res){
db.collection('accounts').find().toArray(function(err, accounts){
  res.send(`<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Simple To-Do App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="display-4 text-center py-1">To-Do App</h1>
      
      <div class="jumbotron p-3 shadow-sm">
        <form action="/create-account" method="POST">
          <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
            <input name="account" autofocus autocomplete="off" class="form-control mr-3" type="text" style="flex: 1;">
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Add New Item</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      
      <ul class="list-group pb-5">
        ${accounts.map(function(account){
          return `<li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
          <span class="item-text">${account.text}</span>
          <div>
            <button class="edit-me btn btn-secondary btn-sm mr-1">Edit</button>
            <button class="delete-me btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>
          </div>
        </li>`
        }).join('')}
      </ul>
    </div>  
  
  </body>
  </html>
  `)  
})  
})

app.post('/create-account', function(req, res){
db.collection('accounts').insertOne({text: req.body.account}, function(){
    res.redirect('/')
})
})
```

Comment: Did you try connecting to mongoAtlas from terminal? You can simply do- mongo "<srv string" to connect? It might be you ip expired. Whitelist your ip and try again

Comment: Check `if (err)`  at first.

Comment: Whitelist ip is 0.0.0.0/0 and I refreshed it from Atlas account but it`s still not working. Atlas database has some connection issue. I even created new account on Atlas but not useful.

Comment: I think the `db()` function expects you to pass the database as a string.

Comment: So, how can I do that as I am beginner?

Comment: But the question is why it sometimes works fine when I start to code it from scratch.